# Issue running juypter notebook after installing Anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I recently installed the latest version of Anaconda which i require for a course i am doing in data analytics.

I need to use jupyter notebook but it won't run for me ..i keep getting an error jupyter notebook not found.

In the anaconda prompt i ran command conda list and juypter is in the list. The version of juputer showing is version 4.4.0.

I tried then to launch jupyter notebook through anaconda navigator but no luck either. I did notice though that in Anaconda navigator the version of juypter notebook shows as 5.6.0. The conda list command shows version 4.4.0. Strange. I then decided from navigator to install version 4.4.0 of jupyter. This has allowed me to run jupyter notebook but i cant code in the notebook and it says kernel not connected. A lot of errors also showing in command prompt.
Any help would be much appreciated as i have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda over 14 times and im getting nowhere. Two assignments due in on the 11th November so getting quite worried. Im very new to programmjng and from a finance background.

Im running windows 7.

Kind regards

Rebecca